# std.deviation of a binomial random variable vs std error of a distribution of sample proportions

Tags: binomial-distribution, standard-error, proportion

For a binomial random variable $Y$ we consider  $\sigma$ to be $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$
but for the $\sigma$ (standard error) of a sampling distribution of proportions we get $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}.$

Why do we take $p/n$ instead of $np$ in the formula for the standard error of the sampling distribution?

Comment: The estimate of the mean for the proportion is Y/n.

Comment: [Basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) -- standard error of $\hat{p}$ is $\text{Var}(\frac{Y}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2} \text{Var}(Y)=p(1-p)/n$

Comment: Also see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176757/why-does-the-standard-error-of-hat-p-sqrtp1-p-n?) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/variance-of-sample-proportion-decreases-with-n-but-of-a-count-increases-with-n?)