# How to calculate sample p (probability of success) for binomial outcome

Tags: p-value, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

I have a question regarding the binomial distribution. I want to calculate the p from the empirical choices during my treatment in order to calculate the standard deviation for my binomial random values (1,0). I have 240 outcomes (1,0) and I know the mean of this outcome but i am missing p to calculate std.

Is there also another way to calculate Std in R instead of using the binomial standard deviation formula? I was thinking of using the estimated variance of a LOGIT model, is that a possibility too?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you code a Bernoulli-distributed variable as 0 and 1, as you have, then the maximum likelihood estimate of $p$ is equal to the sample mean, which you already have. You can also calculate the sample standard deviation (SD) directly from the definition of the SD.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. However, I don't understand the last sentence. What do you eyactly mean by calculatimf the sample SD directly from the definition of the SD. What do you mean by definition? Thx

Comment: @MatthiasVanHerrmann The definition of the sample SD is $\sqrt{\frac{\sum (X - \bar X)^2}N}$.

Comment: Are you sure that I can use the definition of sample SD for a binomial distribution due to the fact that there exists a formula for the binomial SD.

Comment: @MatthiasVanHerrmann Yes. The formula in question is correct because it is implied by the definition.

Comment: @MatthiasVanHerrmann You're welcome. If I answered your question to your satisfaction, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

A proportion does not contain information that can be directly plugged into the 'definition' of a standard deviation, but a commonly used approximate method for calculation of a confidence interval for binomial proportions includes a formula that can be used as an approximation of the standard deviation. See here: [Variance of sample proportion decreases with n but of a count increases with n - why?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/variance-of-sample-proportion-decreases-with-n-but-of-a-count-increases-with-n)

Note, however, that the approximate confidence intervals often have pretty bad coverage. I have argued that different methods should be used. See here: [Putting a confidence interval on the mean of a very rare event](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/putting-a-confidence-interval-on-the-mean-of-a-very-rare-event/15568#15568)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. I have read both of the links you sent me. I cannot find the formula for a confidence interval for binomial proportions. Only the binomial SD formula, where I would need p, which I don't have. How can I derive p from my data? Or shall I take Var(X)/n^2. How can I calculate Var(X)? I am really confused how to plug in those numbers for the formula. Thx

Comment: The p used in the formula is the observed proportion of successes.